# Error: No such file or directory - php

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew

On executing following i get error :

From

```
usr/local/ brew install composer
```

gives error :

> ==> Installing composer from homebrew/php 
>   Error: No such file or directory - php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followings are the steps to fix this error

```
brew install php56 and then
brew link php56 OR brew link --overwrite php56
brew install composer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install composer by following the official guide:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

I'm not sure the brew command still works with composer, and it's fairly easy to install

Comment: When i use php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

i get error -bash: php: command not found

Comment: Well then you need to install php first. `brew install php56` I think